# c# Regex - Match pattern XXX||XXX (text before and after double pipes)

Tags: regex

I have the string below:

```
"g1_fim[7,8] || '/' || g1_fim[5,6] || '/' || g1_fim[1,4] dt_final, campo1, campo2 WHERE **d1_fim || d2_teste** = 'sadasd'"
```

I´d like an regular expression to match X||X  (text before and after double pipes)

The result should be something similar to these two matches:

```
 1. g1_fim[7,8]||'/'||g1_fim[5,6]||'/'||g1_fim[1,4]
 2. d1_fim||d2_teste
```

I´ve tried to use this expression `.*?(\|\|).*?(?=\s)`

Bute the results are:

```
 1. g1_fim[7,8]||'/'||g1_fim[5,6]||'/'||g1_fim[1,4]  ( its ok !!! )
 2.  dt_final, campo1, campo2 WHERE d1_fim||d2_teste  (it´s not ok, I´d like to return here only the 'd1_fim||d2_teste' )
```

Comment: I don't think this is a C# issue. There are several Regex testers on the web with which you can try to find the correct Regex for your string.

Comment: what have u tried and look at the `input` and `output` in ur question..does that help!

Comment: I edited my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you: `\S+(?:\s*\|\|\s*\S+)+`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need the first "word" until whitespace and then what's between WHERE and =. Essentially my suggestion is to look for easier criteria for pattern matching in this case.

Comment: no, because it can have spaces between double pipes, check out my edited question.